# Calculating the resistance between A and B

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

Im tasked to calculate the resistance between A and B, i did a first into it by transforming first upper and very lower triangle into the star transformation and adding the resistances that were in series im unsure whats the next step for me to do? [image]

Here is the next step as proposed -the lower image circuit-:
[image]

Comment: Good start. What happens if you do another star-delta transform on either the upper or the lower triangle of resistors (doesn't really matter which set you choose)?

Comment: thats where im confused idk how/where to plug my delta in the circuit after transform @brhans

Comment: The answer which says you can ignore the middle resistor due to symmetry is correct because there's no current through it, but what I was hinting at is for you to take the middle '3' resistor and combine it with either the top 2 '5' resistors or the bottom 2 '5' resistors as a 'delta' which you could then convert into a 'star'. Once you've done that, further simplification would be ... simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nedd says, you can neglect the two top 3 ohm cross resistors due to symmetry.

Consider your diagram:

[image]

Now imagine that there is non-zero current through the lower cross 3 ohm resistor as shown by the red arrow.  Now rotate the circuit by 180 deg around the vertical red line as shown, the **same** circuit now has the current flowing to the left.  This implies I=-I, hence I = 0.  As there is no current through the resistor, you can remove it without affecting the circuit.

Removing the top two 3 ohm cross resistors makes the problem much simpler.

This **only** works due to the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: Would seem to be sort of a well balanced pine tree bridge.

Comment: even tho i did understand the argument of I=-I, why cant we apply that to the whole circuit for example pick any other resistor and do what you do you get I = 0, no?

Comment: The symmetry just says that there is no net current in any wire / component crossing the red line.  At the junctions on the red line, there may be equal currents going in opposite directions, so no net current crosses the red line.  With the other resistors you find that the direction of the current doesn't reverse in the resistor when the circuit rotates.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in your second step you can just about call it done. "If" your first conversion is correct notice that you have a balanced bridge configuration at the center, so there is no current in the center leg, (just remove it), then combine the parallel legs, - done.

.

**EDIT:**
Your very first D-Y conversion of the top 3-3-3 D section should have been a Y pattern with 1-1-1 ohms each. You would then combine the adjacent 2 ohm resistors to create a new 3-3-3 Y pattern.

The very bottom triangle (1-1-1-1) converts to a single 1 ohm.
Next combine the lower far corner resistors to create a 5-1-5 Y pattern (as you did).
You now have the pattern as in your first redrawn diagram, (except that the top Y pattern is 3-3-3).

The horizontal 3 ohm would still be in the center, but since the bridge pattern is balanced (with 3-5, 3-5) the center resistor can be completely ignored.

All you have left is two connected Y patterns of 3-3-3 and 5-1-5.
The 3+5=8, 8||8=4, then just add the rest.

**Note** that including the D-Y conversion will obviously give the same result as simply ignoring the center resistors from the start. If you do go ahead with the conversions you can still check yourself by using an [online D-Y,Y-D calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/delta-to-wye).

Comment: Please explain to me why the current in the center leg is zero? where i dont see the same voltage in the ends? also where is the source of energy to even talk about current?

Comment: @MOHAMED - See the first example here with a resistance at the center of a balanced bridge.  
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wheatstone-bridge/    Not so sure of your additional steps.

Comment: @MOHAMED - As in the answer from Tesla23 the complete circuit pattern is symmetrical so the voltages at the corresponding points (left and right) will also be equal, hence there will be no current flow in either of the center horizontal resistors, so no conversions were necessary from the start.

Comment: @MOHAMED - The current is assumed just as a mental (visual) example. If you were to physically place ohm meter probes between points A to B you could measure the equivalent resistance (and a real current would flow between point A and B).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Quite possibly you can solve it now?

Comment: so the total resistance is 11 ohm in the end?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI no it's 8 ohms

Comment: ah yea i did a wrong by considering the very upper 3 ohm